# How to use a refresh_token for youtube python api?

Tags: python, youtube-api, google-api-python-client

So i got a refresh token in this way and can I keep it?

And if so, how do I use it next time, so that there is no need for me to open browser?

Right now I'm thinking about creating OAuth2Credentials object directly, is this the right way?

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets, OAuth2Credentials
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.contrib import gce
import httplib2
import webbrowser

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "bot_credentials.json"
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
     CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scope=scope,
redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:65010')
flow.params['include_granted_scopes'] = 'true'
flow.params['access_type'] = 'offline'
auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
webbrowser.open(auth_uri)
url = input('Please enter the redirected url with code')
code = get_url_param(url, 'code')
if code is None:
    print('there is an error in your redirect link with code parameter, check if it exists')
    exit()
print(code)
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code[0])
print(credentials.to_json())#refresh_token here!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user consents to authorize your application to access those resources, Google will return a token to your application. Depending on your application's type, it will either validate the token or exchange it for a different type of token. Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2).

> For example, a server-side web application would exchange the returned token for an access token and a **refresh token**. The access token would let the application authorize requests on the user's behalf, and **the refresh token would let the application retrieve a new access token when the original access token expires.**

Basically, if your application obtains a refresh token during the authorization process, then you will need to periodically use that token to obtain a new, valid access token. Server-side web applications, installed applications, and devices all obtain refresh tokens.

It is stated [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Refreshing_a_Token) that at any time, your application can send a POST request to Google's authorization server that specifies your client ID, your client secret, and the **refresh token** for the user. The request should also set the `grant_type` parameter value to `refresh_token`.

> The following example demonstrates this request:
>
> ```
> POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: accounts.google.com
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> client_id=21302922996.apps.googleusercontent.com&
> client_secret=XTHhXh1SlUNgvyWGwDk1EjXB&
> refresh_token=1/6BMfW9j53gdGImsixUH6kU5RsR4zwI9lUVX-tqf8JXQ&
> grant_type=refresh_token
> ```
>
> The authorization server will return a JSON object that contains a new access token:
>
> ```
> {
>   "access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
>   "expires_in":3920,
>   "token_type":"Bearer"
> }
> ```

You can check this [sample on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/ikai/5905078)  to generate a refresh token for the YouTube API. Note that this will will also create a file called `generate_token.py-oauth` that contains this information.

Comment: But where do I input it next time, refresh token, that is to get a new access_token?